# Databinding from member variables in a class. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, class, xaml, data-binding

Evening all,

I'm working on a WPF application which uses databinding to bind variables of a class to a UI. I've set up my class to incorporate `INotifyPropertyChanged` which is working fine in my other projects. It currently looks like this:

```
 namespace playerWPF
{
    class GameInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public GameInfo(string _teamName) //constructor
        {
            this.TeamName = _teamName;
            this.OppositionName = "Opposition";
            this.TeamScore = 0;
            this.OppositionScore = 0;
            this.Question = "What is your team name?";



        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        private string question;

        public string Question
        {
            get
            {
                return question;
            }
            set
            {
                question = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Question");
            }
        }

//and so on for all the other variables in a similiar fashion
```

My XAML looks like this:

```
    <Window x:Class="playerWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:playerWPF"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Name="MainWindowName">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="112*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="207*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="answerBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="58,60,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Answer here..." VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="submitButton" Content="Submit" Click="submitButton_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="199,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label x:Name="teamNameLabel" Content="{Binding TeamName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25" Width="74"/>
        <Label x:Name="oppositionName" Content="{Binding OppositionName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="328,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="101"/>
        <Label x:Name="responseLabel" Content="{Binding Question}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="58,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="371" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Label x:Name="teamScoreLabel" Content="{Binding TeamScore}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
        <Label x:Name="oppositionScoreLabel" Content="{Binding OppositionScore}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="340,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I initialise a type of this class as a static field in my `MainWindow` like thus: `private static GameInfo gameInfo;`

And in the Main window constructor I assign it a new instance: `gameInfo = new GameInfo("Team");`

It is my understanding that this should change some of the labels on the UI to their default constructed values but this is not the case. Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Also worth mentioning that I have DataContext = this; in my MainWindow constructor as well.

Comment: DataContext should be `gameInfo` and bindings should not include `gameInfo.`, just the property name.

Comment: @Crowcoder I've changed my Bindings and edited my question (though how they will reflect the values in the specific class instance?), but I'm fairly certain that the DataContext needs to be in the constructor of the MainWindow which I have already. I've never seen it put anywhere else

Comment: did you change `DataContext = this;` to `DataContext = gameInfo;`?

Comment: @Crowcoder Right on the money, cheers! Happy to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to utilize `gameInfo` like you would a View Model if you were following the MVVM pattern. So, change

```
DataContext = this; //you don't want the data context to be the window itself
```

to

```
DataContext = gameInfo;
```

Then your bindings are simply

```
{Binding <property name>}
```